# Hybris Payment API

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to find documentation about the Hybris payment API so that I can insert payments made on external payment gateways so that orders inserted gets processed without Hybris itself having to process the actual payment, has anyone ever tried to achieve something like this and is it even possible? I have googled to try and find info but there is nothing out there that I can find, if possible I would like to bypass the payments totally and flag the order itself as paid and have get passed through for delivery directly. Any documentation pointers highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can check adyen hybris plugin at https://github.com/Adyen/adyen-hybris

Adyen is payment provider and support multiple payment method. You can find your way in this plugin source code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can setup payment provider easily by extending the hybris default payment APIs (/paymentdetails, /order etc).
This can be done by creating a new checkoutaddon (if you want to use checkout UI) or by creating a new ycommercewebservice extension and update payment apis.

You can refer Adyen hybris plugin for this which has both variants :
https://github.com/Adyen/adyen-hybris